# Android : Validates resource references inside android xml files

Tags: android, xml

I am getting this error on the **service** tag in AndroidManifest.xml with the "**validates resource references inside android xml files**",

Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>  
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logop"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
    android:name="com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter.GPSTracker"
    android:enabled="true" >
       </service>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter.Homejava"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter.Home"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
         android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
   <activity android:name="com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter.TableView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Gudie me please, Thank you

Here is my GPSTracker.java

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double llatitude; // latitude
double llongitude; // longitude
double altitude;
double bearing;
double accuracy;
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}
public GPSTracker() {

}
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        llatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        llongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            llatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            llongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        llatitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return llatitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        llongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return llongitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

public double getAltitude() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(location != null){
        altitude = location.getAltitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return altitude;
}

public double getBearing() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(location != null){
        bearing = location.getBearing();
    }

    // return longitude
    return bearing;
}

public double getAccuracy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(location != null){
        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
       }

        // return longitude
        return accuracy;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your ManageApps activity is not in the package name space:

```
<activity
android:name="ManageApps"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="net.web44.jimappdev.thecoincollector.manageapps" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The name must start with a . to be considered part of the package name space:

```
  android:name=".ManageApps"
```

Also make sure you have a default constructor in your class. One that has no parameters, like this

```
 public GPSTracker() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar problems if my class does NOT extend `Service` or `IntentService` class.

So verify that `com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter.GPSTracker` really extends one of them.

Also make sure you have a default constructor in your class. One that has no parameters, like this

```
public GPSTracker() {

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have extended Service

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about the error. If you click Ctrl + F1 / CMD + 1 you can get a bit more details about the error.

Comment: com.example.softwaredeveloper.pwrmeter.GPSTracker has no default constructor
validatres resource references inside android xml files

Comment: public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

 private final Context mContext;

Comment: Edited my answer - just add a default constructor (one without any parameters) and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, will try it @Vesko

Comment: Sure! Just post if it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I have an constructor, but it has Context parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86979/discussion-between-ram-kumar-and-vesko).

Comment: when i add that constructor, I am getting the following error
Service()  in service cannot be applied to (java.lang.string)